# How do I remove my photos from iCloud?

Tags: icloud

I've disabled iCloud photo storage and am trying to get my 296 photos onto my PC before they're deleted after 30 days. Do I have to install iCloud and set it up on my PC to get my photos or is there a way I can do it without having to do that?

Comment: Open a browser and log into iCloud.com using your appleId

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install the iCloud utility, you can go to [iCloud Web Page](http://www.icloud.com), choose Photos and select all the pics you want to download.
But you have to click on every photo to download the entire collection, I did't find any "Select All" option (even CMD + A does't work).
But anyway, you're lucky, we're talking about 'just' 296 photos ;)